# Calculate new variables from a dataset and save them with a new dimension

Tags: python-xarray

I have a Dataset ds with the variables Var_1, Var_2 and Var_3, which are all physical quantities, temperature, density and pressure.

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:                         (Altitude: 100)
Coordinates:
  * Altitude                        (Altitude) float64
Data variables:
    Var_1                           (Altitude) float64
    Var_2                           (Altitude) float64
    Var_3                           (Altitude) float64
```

I calculate a new variable "Heat" which I want to add to my dataset along the dimension "Altitude" and along a new dimension "Energy_Type" with two entries. The already existing variables cannot be assigned to this new dimension.

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:                         (Altitude: 100, Energy_Type: 2 )
Coordinates:
  * Altitude                        (Altitude) float64
  * New_Dim                         (Energy_Type) object 'Sensible' 'Latent'
Data variables:
    Var_1                           (Altitude) float64
    Var_2                           (Altitude) float64
    Var_3                           (Altitude) float64
    Heat                            (Altitude, Energy_Type) float64
```

I also use two other xarray datasets in the calculation which I do not need to save.

```
sensible = xr.Dataset()
sensible['Heat'] = ds.Var_1 * Dataset_X * ds.Var_2
sensible.coords['Energy_Type'] = "Sensible"
sensible = sensible.expand_dims('Energy_Type')

latent = xr.Dataset()
latent['Heat'] = ds.Var_1 * Dataset_Y * ds.Var_3
latent.coords['Energy_Type'] = "Latent"
latent = latent.expand_dims('Energy_Type')

ds = xr.merge([ds, sensible, latent])
```

While this is working, it doesn't look like the best approach for me. Am I missing an easy xarray functionality which could help me do this better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you are essentially treating `Var_2` and `Var_3` as slices along `new_dim`. You could concatenate them along this dim:

```
In [3]: reindexed_2_3 = xr.concat(
   ...:     [ds.Var_2, ds.Var_3],
   ...:     dim=pd.Index(['a', 'b'], name='New_Dim'))
   ...:
```

This allows you to do math with the combined array like you normally would:

```
In [4]: new_var = ds.Var_1 * reindexed_2_3
```

You could of course add this back into the original dataset:

```
In [5]: ds['New_Var'] = new_var

In [6]: ds
Out[6]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:   (Altitude: 100, New_Dim: 2)
Coordinates:
  * Altitude  (Altitude) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 ...
  * New_Dim   (New_Dim) object 'a' 'b'
Data variables:
    Var_1     (Altitude) float64 0.4059 0.4675 0.28 0.7884 0.523 0.6433 ...
    Var_2     (Altitude) float64 0.7325 0.4088 0.7504 0.2138 0.8064 0.4313 ...
    Var_3     (Altitude) float64 0.5138 0.6193 0.5576 0.6782 0.9428 0.7201 ...
    New_Var   (Altitude, New_Dim) float64 0.2973 0.2086 0.1911 0.2895 0.2101 ...
```

Though if the concatenated object is more helpful for other operations you could create a new dataset with the set of coordinates:

```
In [7]: xr.Dataset({'reindexed_2_3': reindexed_2_3, 'new_var': new_var})
Out[7]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:        (Altitude: 100, New_Dim: 2)
Coordinates:
  * Altitude       (Altitude) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 ...
  * New_Dim        (New_Dim) object 'a' 'b'
Data variables:
    reindexed_2_3  (New_Dim, Altitude) float64 0.7325 0.4088 0.7504 0.2138 ...
    new_var        (Altitude, New_Dim) float64 0.2973 0.2086 0.1911 0.2895 ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your exhaustive answer. I am really sorry, but I oversimplified my question too much and this makes your approach quite tough to apply. I will edit my question to clarify my problem.

Comment: Without knowing anything about Dataset_X and Dataset_Y, it's hard to know what isn't working. But in general, the indexing approach I suggested above will work. If Dataset_X and Y should be multiplied by `sensible` and `latent`, respectively, you could concatenate these along this dimension as well, and your final answer becomes as simple as `ds.Var_1 * concat_XY * reindexed_2_3`

Comment: The problem is, if I do this is, the code, from a physics point of view, will become much harder to understand for people who don't know xarray. In my actual code it is `sensible = density * specific_heat_capacity * temperature` and `latent = density * latent_heat * specific_humidity`. If I split up the 2nd and 3rd parts into combined dataset before multiplying, my co-workers, who know physics, will have to think a long time about what's happening. The code I am using right now is quite easy to understand, but I think there has to be a more straightforward and easier way to understand too.

Comment: I see. that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the answer of @delgadom (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52681787/7950930) I found a satisfying solution for me and will post it here.

```
sensible = ds.Var_1 * Dataset_X * ds.Var_2
latent = ds.Var_1 * Dataset_Y * ds.Var_3
Heat = xr.concat(
    [sensible, latent],
    dim=pd.Index(['sensible','latent'],name='Energy_type'))
ds['Heat'] = Heat
```

With this the code is shorter and better to understand than before.

I also found the answer right at http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/combining.html#concatenate, but I couldn't understand it earlier.